# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (111 "Connection refused") centos 6

Tags: mysql, sockets, mariadb

Centos 6, openlitespeed installed, using MariaDB

MySQL works normally until it suddenly stops and can't start

```
[root@backup ~]# service mysql start
Starting MySQL.170815 09:56:24 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/lib/mysql/backup.err'.
170815 09:56:24 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
..... ERROR!
```

/var/lib/mysql/backup.err:

```
170814 06:44:02 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
2017-08-14  6:44:02 3069880736 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.1.25-MariaDB) starting as process 3250 ...
2017-08-14  6:44:02 3069880736 [Note] InnoDB: innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm has been changed to legacy because of small buffer pool size. In order to use backoff, increase buffer pool at least up to 20MB.

2017-08-14  6:44:02 3069880736 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2017-08-14  6:44:02 3069880736 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2017-08-14  6:44:02 3069880736 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2017-08-14  6:44:02 3069880736 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __sync_synchronize() is used for memory barrier
2017-08-14  6:44:02 3069880736 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2017-08-14  6:44:02 3069880736 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2017-08-14  6:44:02 3069880736 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2017-08-14  6:44:02 3069880736 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2017-08-14  6:44:02 3069880736 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-08-14  6:44:02 3069880736 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2017-08-14  6:44:02 3069880736 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=2657313375
2017-08-14  6:44:02 3069880736 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite buffer...
InnoDB: Set innodb_force_recovery to ignore this error.
2017-08-14  6:44:02 3069880736 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2017-08-14  6:44:02 3069880736 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2017-08-14  6:44:02 3069880736 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2017-08-14  6:44:02 3069880736 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2017-08-14  6:44:02 3069880736 [ERROR] Aborting

Error in my_thread_global_end(): 1 threads didn't exit
170814 06:44:07 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/backup.pid ended
```

Test MySQL:

```
[root@backup ~]# mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (111 "Connection refused")
```

/etc/my.cnf :

```
#
[client] 
port = 3306 
socket = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
# This group is read both both by the client and the server
# use it for options that affect everything
#
[client-server]

#
# include all files from the config directory
#
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d
```

/etc/my.cnf.d/server.cnf:

```
#
# These groups are read by MariaDB server.
# Use it for options that only the server (but not clients) should see
#
# See the examples of server my.cnf files in /usr/share/mysql/
#

# this is read by the standalone daemon and embedded servers
[server]

# this is only for the mysqld standalone daemon
[mysqld]

#
# * Galera-related settings
#
[galera]
# Mandatory settings
#wsrep_on=ON
#wsrep_provider=
#wsrep_cluster_address=
#binlog_format=row
#default_storage_engine=InnoDB
#innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
#
# Allow server to accept connections on all interfaces.
#
#bind-address=0.0.0.0
#
# Optional setting
#wsrep_slave_threads=1
#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0

# this is only for embedded server
[embedded]

# This group is only read by MariaDB servers, not by MySQL.
# If you use the same .cnf file for MySQL and MariaDB,
# you can put MariaDB-only options here
[mariadb]

# This group is only read by MariaDB-10.1 servers.
# If you use the same .cnf file for MariaDB of different versions,
# use this group for options that older servers don't understand
[mariadb-10.1]
```

I have already uninstalled MariaDB server and client, then reinstalled it but it still doesn't work.

```
[root@backup ~]# service mysql restart
 ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!
Starting MySQL.170815 11:33:12 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/lib/mysql/backup.err'.
170815 11:33:12 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
..... ERROR!
 ERROR! Failed to restart server.
[root@backup ~]# mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (111 "Connection refused")
```

grep "socket"

```
[root@backup ~]# mysqld --verbose --help | grep "socket"
2017-08-15 18:05:44 3070110112 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
                      Buffer length for TCP/IP and socket communication
  --performance-schema-max-socket-classes=#
                      Maximum number of socket instruments.
  --performance-schema-max-socket-instances=#
                      Maximum number of opened instrumented sockets. Use 0 to
                      the slave off the socket once the slave connects. Due to
  --socket=name       Socket file to use for connection
performance-schema-max-socket-classes                      10
performance-schema-max-socket-instances                    -1
socket                                                     /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

What could possibly be going wrong?

Comment: It seems like your my.cnf file is missing the socket path. you can find this normally in /etc/mysql/my.cnf or /etc/my.cnf or ~/.my.cnf.

Comment: i has added socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock but still not working

Comment: Could you update your post with the my.cnf file ? after you added did you try to restart mysql ?

Comment: @Noob done but still not working

Comment: [client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

This is the start of my.cnf file @doctorseo

Comment: @Noob done, now: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")

Comment: @docterSEO you have to check whats the path name of the mysqld.sock in your Operating System. Use "mysqld --verbose --help | grep ^socket" to find the correct path.

Comment: @Noob i has updated correct path socket /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock , then restarting mysql still error (111 "Connection refused")

Comment: add "bind-address            = 127.0.0.1" to your my.cnf file @doctorseo

Comment: @Noob done, i has try some bind-address, output: mysql: unknown variable 'bind-address=127.0.0.1' , mysql: unknown variable 'bind-address=localhost' , mysql: unknown variable 'bind-address=0.0.0.0'

Comment: the best solution i would remove all mysql instances and installing it again!